# Javascript - confused using confirm in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

Here's the ajax

```
$('#delete_button').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    confirmDelete();

    $.ajax({
            url:      del_link,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data) {
                          location.replace(data.redirect_url);
                      }
    });
});
```

and in a separate JS file I have

```
function confirmDelete() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
}
```

When I click 'Cancel' on the confirm dialog, the Ajax runs (when it should not).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your live function, replace

```
confirmDelete();
```

with:

```
if (!confirmDelete()) return false;
```

Comment: The function will return a boolean value you should do something with - as suggested in this answer return false would not run the rest of it.